# c# unity ошибка CS1519 Помогите решить

Tags: c#, unity3d

Помогите исправить ошибку код предоставил и скриншот ошибки тоже и текст ошибки .помогите плиз что нужно сделать максимально разжуйте.

error CS1519: Invalid token ',' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваша проблема в незнании языка. А ошибка в том, что Вы что-то делаете за пределами метода

Comment: на примере можете подсказать как исправить ?

Comment: Приведите код в текстовом виде

Answer (score 1):

Вы вставили исполняемый код непосредственно в тело класса, так делать нельзя. В классе можно создать метод, в котором будет находится исполняемый код.
Больше информации вы сможете найти в
[кратком обзоре языка c#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы понять в чём ваша проблема, вам надо для начала понять - [что такое калсс](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.1.php)?

> Класс представляет новый тип, который определяется пользователем.

---

[Что может содержать класс](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHWL_ruAM842AM842&sxsrf=ALeKk02sSTbQGifTP8olh8UBLHc6sqWw9Q%3A1597234281561&ei=adwzX4XeIYi0UoDGjeAH&q=%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2+%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5+%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81+C%23&oq=%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2+%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5+%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81+C%23&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJzoECAAQRzoHCCMQsAIQJ1Cw1RxYxYAdYK6JHWgBcAF4AIAB1AGIAbcHkgEFMC40LjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjFtuav0ZXrAhUImhQKHQBjA3wQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)?

> **Класс может содержать в себе следующие члены:**
>
> - Конструкторы
> - Константы
> - Поля
> - Методы;
> - Свойства
> - Операторы
> - Вложенные типы данных
> - Деструкторы

---

То есть можно делать вывод что в классе не должно быть присваивания, операторы и.т.д.
А в вашем коде вы напрямую написали действия в классе.

---

П.Н.
Код не буду кидать. Проблема очень лёгкая, разберётесь сами.

Comment: Скинь код пожалуйста . Если бы я знал как решить я решил бы без сайта этого!